# Проверить, находится ли слово внутри тега

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим есть следующие случаи:

```
1 `<b>text</b>`

2. `<b class="name">text</b>`

3.
```

```
<b class="
    name
   ">
text</b>
```

Как вытаскивать в этих случаях только слова `text`?

Comment: Во всех трёх случаях одинаково справится любой нормальный html-парсер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `bs4` и распарсить `HTML`.

***Пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    html = '<b class="name">text</b>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    result = soup.b.get_text()
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
text
```